# configuration system failed to initialize app.config .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, app-config, configuration-files

I have a WPF application that uses app.config. I set the app.config file as described in 
[Read/Write App.Config File with .NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET-2-0)
so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="BDViewerLog.txt"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>  
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" sku="Client"/></startup><system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1Soap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="Service1Soap1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:9139/Service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap" contract="ServiceReferenceBDV.Service1Soap"
        name="Service1Soap" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:9139/Service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap1" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1Soap"
        name="Service1Soap1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>  
    <appSettings>
      <add key="Path1" value="C:\files\Accounts.txt"/>
      <add key="PathMD5" value="C:\files\md5Accounts.txt"/>
      <add key ="LogUserActions" value="C:\files\Log.txt"/>      
    </appSettings> 

</configuration>
```

in c# code:
`string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path1"];`

I need to read the paths to files in appSettings node but I keep getting the error
Configuration system failed to initialize. I looked for a solution in similar topics but none applied to my case.
I checked the file multiple times, couldn't find an error.
I also tried deleting all filed from \Debug, \Obj and cleaning and rebuilding the solution but nothing worked.
I don't know what more to do.

Fixed it:
I didn't add this in front of the appender section:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
   <appender ...>
   </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: check the inner exception

Comment: hm, it says [System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException] {"Unrecognized configuration section appender. (C\\App.vshost.exe.Config line 4)"} System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException if I comment the appender section it works! but i still need it to read the appender section... and it seems it is not doing it right

Comment: You should also have mentioned that it was for log4net.  That is useful information!!